# MSBuild fails on "Invalid command line switch for "LC.exe" Why?

Tags: .net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am creating our companies continuous integration server using cc.net, and my original attempted included visual studio being installed on the build server. My manager really wants the build server to not need VS installed, and to just use MSBuild, included in the .net installation.

My current problem though is that I am receiving the following error message:

> error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "LC.exe". Illegal
>   characters in path. [C:\path\to\project.csproj]

With visual studio 2010 installed in my previous attempt, my build works successfully, but now that I do not have visual studio installed in the new build machine, I am receiving this message.

What can I do to get this to work? Thanks in advance for your help!

*update 8/13/2012* below is my cc.net msbuild task:

```
  <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>D:\Build</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>Trunk\BuildSolution.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /t:CLEAN,BUILD</buildArgs>
    <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
    <timeout>600</timeout>
  </msbuild>
```

Comment: could you submit the CCNET task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lc.exe (licence compiler) comes with the .net framework sdk as well as studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988

Try downloading the right sdk and make sure your path is updated to point to the install directory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Simon, I have this installed, but the path was not added to the global path variable. I was able to explicitly pass it to the build call, and it is now able to compile